# Write file on server in flex web application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am trying to build a application which can record sound in Flex 4. I am able to record sound but i am not able to save sound data in a file on web.

How can i save sound data on server in flex web application. FileStream does not work in flex web application.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some solutions which allow to perform upload from byte array like [the following](http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=139). But don't forget about some [security restrictions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#contentType) which can require user interaction on upload.